# SQL Server 2008 - Reporting Services Failed Login for User '...'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Good Afternoon,

I'm having difficulty running a report with a data source saved on the Report Server using credentials for a user I created on SQL Server named 'ReportUser'.  Attempting to resolve this I've mapped the user to the 'ReportServer' database with the db_owner role as well as setting the default database to the 'ReportServer'.  However, each time I attempt to run the report I receive the error message:

**Cannot create a connection to data source 'Test'.  Login failed for user 'ReportUser'.**

I'm running SQL Server 2008 from my local machine and am able to successfully run the reports when I setup the datasource using Windows Authentication.  Any idea on what could be causing the issues when attempting to use the SQL Authentication with the 'ReportUser'

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are you using the Report Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your reply.

I believe I found the cause of my issue.  Since this was a local install for testing purposes I just set up the instance of SQL Server with Windows Authentication.  However, I made the mistake of not setting up the server for both Windows and SQL Authentication.  The following link helped me resolve this.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1784261.aspx/1?Could+not+connect+to+database+login+failed+for+user+sa

After changing this setting and restarting the SQL Server everything appears to be running properly now.